# CVS get the last committer name

Tags: cvs

Ok I know CVS is an old technology and a lot a new fun things exists nowadays... but I still need to use it.

Do you know which command I need to use to get the name of the last committer of a file?

I already use `cvs status` to get the list of modified files.
But for those files, I need the committer's name.

Is there an argument of `cvs status` to get this information or is there an other command?

Comment: I don't think CVS provides such functionality. Your best option may be to just parse the output of `cvs log` which shows you committer names. eg. something like `cvs log <filename> | grep author | head -1 | ...`